# Make JPA do not change the structure of existing database

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wonder is it possible ? 
For example there is a constraint in my database *ON DELETE SET NULL* but I can't set this constraint in JPA (as I know there is not supported). So when JPA update my database it will remove this constraint (am I right?) but I won't it.

Comment: Why would JPA update your database schema? It won't, unless you explicitly configure it to do it.

Comment: If you are using hibernate then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just to reiterate what others have already told you ... it is YOUR configuration that tells JPA to update the schema, and you don't share what your configuration is so nobody can say any more about it.

Secondly, you certainly CAN configure JPA to define `ForeignKey` constraints. To do this you make use of the "`foreignKeyDefinition`" attribute (of the annotation/XML element) defining the full FK info. See [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/annotations.html#ForeignKey) for the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

JPA doesn't update the schema unless specifically configured to. If you don't have this set up, then you won't need to worry about JPA updating the database and removing this constraint.